Continuity of radii of balls function
Assume $X$ is a nice enough metric space. Assume  $U$ is an open set in $X$. Is it true that there exists a continuous function $f:U\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ such that $B_{u}(f(u))\subseteq U$ for all $u\in U$? Here, $B_u(f(u))$ is open ball at $u$ with radius $f(u)$.
Observations and remarks:

By definition of open set, there exists a function $\overline{f}:U\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ but it doesn't have to be continuous.

If $X$ is finite with discrete metric, define $f:X\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ by $f(x)=1/2$. If $U$ open in $X$, then for $u\in U$, $B_{u}(f(u))=\{u\}\subseteq U$.



@SassatelliGiulio edited

@SassatelliGiulio the original $f$ was a red herring - im just asking for the construction of some f.

You can take $f(u)=\min{1,\inf_{x\notin U} d(x,u)}$, which is continuous (in fact, non-expansive).

@SassatelliGiulio Why not just $f(u)= d(X-U,u)$?

Because if $X=U$ you don't want it to be $\infty$, but for $U\subsetneq X$ that's OK too.
